# sed command behaves differently

Tags: ruby, sed

I'm trying to strip the version number in a string using the following sed command:

```
sed -E "s/\-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*\-?[0-9]*\.?/./g"
```

So this transforms the string "abc-de-sap-web-1.0.152.war" to "abc-de-sap-web.war". This works find when run as a bash command. However, I'm trying to run this through a ruby script. So I have tried the below command:

```
tar_name = `echo "abc-de-sap-web-1.0.152.war" | sed -E "s/\-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*\-?[0-9]*\.?/./g"`
```

puts "tar_name"

However, now the output is "abc-de-sap-web.ar". It takes off the "w" character as well.

Any reason why?

Comment: Why not use Ruby `.gsub`?  `tar_name = tar_name.gsub(/-(?:[0-9]+\.){2}[0-9.-]*/, '.')`? But the problem is that `\.?` in `"..."` gets interpreted as `.`, any char.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, the gsub command actually worked for me. For now, I will use this to get the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `\.?` inside a double quoted string literal was interpreted as `.` that matches any character.

I suggest using Ruby `gsub`:

```
tar_name = tar_name.gsub(/-(?:[0-9]+\.){2}[0-9.-]*/, '.')
```

See the [Rubular regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/K4Z6h67gTii8xC).

**Details**

- `-` - a hyphen
- `(?:[0-9]+\.){2}` - two repetitions of 1+ digits and a dot
- `[0-9.-]*` - 0 or more digits, dots or hyphens

The matches are replaced with a single dot.